# Remove Rows From CSV Where A Specific Column Matches An Input File

Tags: csv, grep, row

I have a CSV that contains multiple columns and rows [File1.csv].

I have another CSV file (just one column) that lists a specific words [File2.csv].

I want to able to take remove rows within File1 if any columns match any of the words listed in File2.

I originally used this:

```
 grep -v -F -f File2.csv File1.csv > File3.csv
```

This worked, to a certain extent. This issue I ran into was with columns that had more than word in it (ex. word1,word2,word3). File2 contained word2 but did not delete that row.

I tired spreading the words apart to look like this: (word1 , word2 , word3), but the original command did not work.

How can I remove a row that contains a word from File2 and may have other words in it?

Answer (score 1):

One way using `awk`.

Content of `script.awk`:

```
BEGIN {
    ## Split line with a doble quote surrounded with spaces.
    FS = "[ ]*\"[ ]*"
}

## File with words, save them in a hash.
FNR == NR {
    words[ $2 ] = 1;
    next;
}

## File with multiple columns.
FNR < NR {
    ## Omit line if eigth field has no interesting value or is first line of
    ## the file (header).
    if ( $8 == "N/A" || FNR == 1 ) {
        print $0
        next
    }

    ## Split interested field with commas. Traverse it searching for a
    ## word saved from first file. Print line only if not found.

    ## Change due to an error pointed out in comments.
    ##--> split( $8, array, /[ ]*,[ ]*/ )
    ##--> for ( i = 1; i <= length( array ); i++ ) {
    len = split( $8, array, /[ ]*,[ ]*/ )
    for ( i = 1; i <= len; i++ ) {
    ## END change.

        if ( array[ i ] in words ) {
            found = 1
            break
        }
    }
    if ( ! found ) {
        print $0
    }
    found = 0
}
```

Assuming `File1.csv` and `File2.csv` have content provided in comments of *Thor's* answer (I suggest to add that information to the question), run the script like:

```
awk -f script.awk File2.csv File1.csv
```

With following output:

```
"DNSName","IP","OS","CVE","Name","Risk"
"ex.example.com","1.2.3.4","Linux","N/A","HTTP 1.1 Protocol Detected","Information"
"ex.example.com","1.2.3.4","Linux","CVE-2011-3048","LibPNG Memory Corruption Vulnerability (20120329) - RHEL5","High"
"ex.example.com","1.2.3.4","Linux","CVE-2012-2141","Net-SNMP Denial of Service (Zero-Day) - RHEL5","Medium"
"ex.example.com","1.2.3.4","Linux","N/A","Web Application index.php?s=-badrow Detected","High"
"ex.example.com","1.2.3.4","Linux","CVE-1999-0662","Apache HTTPD Server Version Out Of Date","High"
"ex.example.com","1.2.3.4","Linux","CVE-1999-0662","PHP Unsupported Version Detected","High"
"ex.example.com","1.2.3.4","Linux","N/A","HBSS Common Management Agent - UNIX/Linux","High"
```

Comment: @eloscurosecreto: Are you running it directly from command line? I mean, paste it without using a file.

Comment: I created a .awk file, that was the issue. I just ran your code directly from cli and it completed without any issues, however, I spot checked the output with the remove file and found multiple instances of words within rows that should have been deleted. This method seems to just have deleted the rows which contained a single word (w/o the ",word2,word3") in a column.

Comment: @eloscurosecreto: I've edited my answer based in the examples provided in comments of *Thor's* answer.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out with this Birei. I'm running into a issue at line 24 in the script, I'm getting a `awk: script.awk: line 24: illegal reference to array array`. I actually tried to correct the issue before responding, but I am completely lost with awk.

Comment: @eloscurosecreto: Which version of `awk`? Mine is `GNU Awk 4.0.1` and it worked without problem. I've edited the script and now I hope it works for your version too.

Comment: Does anyone remember the original example CSV files? What keyword were provided?  Also I dont see 8 fields in the result here, only 6?

Comment: @ethanpil: You can get both files from eloscurosecreto's comment in Thor's answer. The eight field is right because I changed the `Field Separator` variable. So, each double quote character separates fields, not each comma.

Comment: Thanks Birei, I didnt think to look down below :).  To make it easier and more permanent I posted to PasteBin: [File1.csv](http://pastebin.com/2d9tB14u) [File2.csv](http://pastebin.com/qiFH9ysX)

Answer (score 0):

You could convert split lines containing multiple patterns in `File2.csv`.

Below uses `tr` to convert lines containing `word1,word2` into separate lines before using them as patterns. The `<()` construct temporarily acts as a file/fifo (tested in `bash`):

```
grep -v -F -f <(tr ',' '\n' < File2.csv) File1.csv > File3.csv
```

Comment: So I tried your method and I am still left with the same results as `grep -v -F -f File2.csv File1.csv > File3.csv`

Comment: Then you need to show us exact samples of `File1.csv` and `File2.csv`. The above works with what you've provided so far.

Comment: Here are the links to the files:

- [File1.csv](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ryrk0ofenzzmfuj/File1.csv)
- [Files2.csv](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o59t2lfobgjugd5/File2.csv)

I hope this helps. Thank you!

Comment: No items in `File2.csv` match `File1.csv`.

Comment: Sorry about that, try these links: [File1.csv](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/21425304/File1.csv) & [File2.csv](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/21425304/File2.csv).

Comment: @eloscurosecreto, these are the same files. None of the items in `File2.csv` match any line in `File1.csv`. In addition these cannot be the files you are having trouble with, no lines in `File2.csv` have comma separated items.

Comment: Hi Thor, I'm not sure what happened there, but CVE's from file2 should match CVE's in file1 that have multiples within the CVE column.